# React: How do I only render a component on the page once I click on it from a mapped array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I've got a grid of components rendered on a page using the map function and I want to only render the component with all it's details once  I click on it and only manage to get an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logo')

I'm new to React and can't figure out why this is happening.

Some help would be much appreciated!

Here's my code:

**Body component - (parent component)**

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import CompanyList from "./CompanyList";
import Company from "./Company";

const Body = ({ companies }) => {
  const [viewCompany, setViewCompany] = useState(false);
  const showCompanyHandler = (company) => {
    console.log("Clicked on company card");
    setViewCompany(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="appBody">
      <CompanyList
        companies={companies}
        showCompanyHandler={showCompanyHandler}
      />
      {viewCompany && <Company />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

**CompanyList component (child of Body)**

```js
import Company from "./Company";

const CompanyList = ({ companies, showCompanyHandler }) => {
  return (
    <div className="companyList">
      {companies.map((company) => (
        <Company
          key={company.id}
          company={company}
          showCompanyHandler={showCompanyHandler}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CompanyList;
```

**Company component (child of CompanyList) - Component I want to display on the page**

```js
const Company = ({ company, showCompanyHandler }) => {
  return (
    <div className="company" onClick={(company) => showCompanyHandler(company)}>
      {console.log(company)}
      <img src={company.logo} alt="logo" />
      <h1>{company.name}</h1>
      <p>{company.companyDescription}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Company;
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your code structure is broken and you need to refactor it to implement the kind of logic that you're looking for.

First of all, I would suggest that you remove this `{viewCompany && <Company />}`, `viewCompany` and `showCompanyHandler` from your Body component.

Since the Company component will always be visible, IMO it should be responsible for handling this "expand" logic that you're trying to implement, something like:

```js
const Company = ({ company }) => {
  const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = useState(false);
  const toggleShowDetails = () => setShowDetails(!showDetails);
  return (
    <div className="company" onClick={toggleShowDetails}>
      {showDetails &&
      <>
        <img src={company.logo} alt="logo" />
        <h1>{company.name}</h1>
        <p>{company.companyDescription}</p>
      </>
    }
      </div>
  );
};

export default Company;
```

As you can see, with this implementation you no longer have to pass `showCompanyHandler` to the Company component and you can remove all of this logic from the Body component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel. Maybe I wasn't too clear in formulating the question, but the idea is that if a user clicks on a company card in the list, it should just render only that company on the page, with all the details that particular company has.
Your code works if you want to toggle the company view. Thanks anyway

Comment: You're welcome Andrei! What you can try then is to apply this logic that I suggested but in the `CompanyList` component! What you absolutely cannot do is render a `Company` component without props like you're trying to at the `Body` component. This might be confusing to you as you're just learning React but this renders a new and independent Company component that has nothing to do with the ones that you're rendering at `CompanyList`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out for me, Daniel, it makes more sense now. I'm getting the error because the Company component isn't getting any props like I was expecting.

Do you think a way I can go about this is to use React Router and add a dynamic link to the Company component rendered in the CompanyList ? That would maybe render the right Company component on the page.

Comment: If you want to render the Company component on a different route that would work, yes. You could also use global state (with something like React's Context) to pass company data to your component. If Company remains as a child of CompanyList you can just pass the current company data as props.

Answer (score 0):

If CompanyList component is working fine, an easy way to do it would be to use a function to dynamically generate the list instead of having a direct reference to the component.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import CompanyList from "./CompanyList";
import Company from "./Company";

const Body = ({ companies }) => {
  const [viewCompany, setViewCompany] = useState(false);

  const showCompanyHandler = () => {
    console.log("Clicked on company card");
    setViewCompany(true);
  };

  // I removed the showCompanyHandler attribute and 
  // added an onClick to CompanyListContainer, instead.
  const generateCompanyList = (companies) => {
    if (viewCompany === false) return null;
    return <CompanyList companies={companies} />
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="appBody">
      <CompanyListContainer onClick={showCompanyHandler}>
          {generateCompanyList}
      </CompanyList>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

If generateCompanyList is null, there should be nothing to click on, unfortunately. So, you could add some styles to it the div for a minimum width/height, or, you can move that onClick to your appBody component.